# Symfony sql query array in array

Tags: symfony, multidimensional-array, repository, where-clause, entitymanager

I’m look for multiple Items objects matching with state (in Orders):

I have 3 tables:

1. Items.
2. Orders (with number order, state, etc) OneToMany with OrderDetails,
   ManyToOne with Items.
3. OrderDetails (with detail for 1 orders: id_item, orders_id…)
   ManyToOne with Orders, , ManyToOne with Items.

Order (with state) -> OrderDetails (with items)

I would like to write the request for "example" (‘Order.state'):

$order = $this->entityManager->getRepository(OrderDetails::class)->findBy([‘items => $id_item, ‘Order.state' => 2], ['id' => 'desc']);

How to write this query correctly? Maybe I need a function in items repository?
Thank in advance.

Edit (after your help, thank you):
I add function in repository:
in th first time I made an sql query and tested it in phpmyadmin to be sure of what I wanted:
My sql (may be not perfect, but which works)

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    c.state_id,
    i.itemno,
    o.quantity,
    u.code,
    u.id AS idcustomer,
    c.customers_id 
    FROM
    items AS p,
    order AS c,
    order_details AS o,
    customers AS u 
    WHERE
    c.state_id = 1 
    AND i.id = 1 
    AND c.customers_id = u.id
```

Here my code in symfony, but I have an error in JOIN (I am not sure of the syntax).

```
            $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
             'SELECT
                 i.id,
                 c.state_id,
                 i.itemno,
                 o.quantity,
                 u.code,
                 u.id AS idcustomer,
                 c.customers_id

             JOIN
                i.Items o,
                o.Order c,
                c.Customers u
             FROM
                 App\Entity\Items AS i,
                 App\Entity\Order AS c,
                 App\Entity\OrderDetails AS o,
                 App\Entity\Customers AS u
             WHERE c.state_id IN (:ostate)
                 AND i.id IN (:items_id)
                 AND c.customers_id IN (u.id)
             '
         )->setParameter('items_id', $items_id)
          ->setParameter('ostate', $ostate);

return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Yes you cannot use findBy, findOneBy with a property from another entity, so you need to do your own function in your repository using DQL (or sql)

Comment: Yo must follow the Symfony doc : https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository